# Remove duplicate words from a sentence without using regex in c++?

Tags: c++, c++20

I would like to remove duplicate word from the sentence without using regex in c++. For example:

Input: `Welcome to to the world of of digital computers computers.`

Expected Output: `Welcome to the world of digital computers.`

Actual output: `Welcome to the world of digital computers computers.`

How I can manage that in the below code ??

```
void removeDupWord(string str)
{
    // Used to split string around spaces.
    istringstream ss(str);

    // To store individual visited words
    unordered_set<string> hsh;

    // Traverse through all words
    do
    {
        string word;
        ss >> word;

        // If current word is not seen before.
        while (hsh.find(word) == hsh.end()) {
            cout << word << " ";
            hsh.insert(word);
        }

    } while (ss);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: problem is that it prints the below output. ?

Comment: `computers` are duplicated, because you are not checking if word has some chars that are not a letters (here `.`), try to test it without `.` at the end of the sentence

Comment: withou '.' it works...But that is mandatory. Input cannot be change...

Comment: `ss >> word;` can fail, but you don't check until AFTER using the bad value. Always read, check, then use or handle the error. so... `string word; while (ss >> word) { /*do stuff*/ }`.

Comment: That inner while should be an if

Comment: And you might be able to take advantage of [`hsh.contains(word)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/contains) if your tools are up-to-date.

Comment: To fix the problem @Bonniu points out you need to check for trailing punctuation 
 and then `pop_back` to remove it before looking for duplicates. Remember that you pooped it, though because you'll have to print it out later so it's not lost.

Comment: Unrelated to the bug you're seeing, but at least in my experience, rather than "if word not found in set, print it out and insert it", it's cleaner and easier (and faster) to use: "if inserting word in set succeeded, print it out".

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but why `while (hsh.` instead of `if (hsh.`? Please only tag the language version you're using, not all of them

Comment: should only consecutive duplicates be removed?

Comment: `unordered set` may not be your best bet. You need some way to check adjacency as well. What of the sentence `"I went to Mars and I went to Veus."`? You don't want `"I went to Mars and I went Venus."` do you? You could use `hash` and a `std::string last = word;` and add the condition `last == word` before choosing to eliminate the current word.

Comment: You also have the problem of `"computers"` and `"computers."` not being the same word due to the `'.'` at the end of the second. You can use a `.erase()` with `std::remove_if()` to check for `std::ispunct()` to trim any punctuation from the end to make a valid comparison between them.

Comment: Or even simpler, just use `word.back()` to check if it is punctuation, save it and then use `word.pop_back()` to remove it and then compare.

Comment: I haven't looked carefully, but my impression is that this code would transform "I want to go to bed" into "I want to go bed". Just read a word at a time and check whether the newly read word is the same as the previous word. No hash table in sight! Just an extra string to hold the previously read word.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin -- I think (haven't read the code carefully) that "I went to Mars and I went to Venus" would get transformed into "I went to Mars and Venus". Which isn't bad, but is almost certainly not what was intended.

Comment: @PeteBecker - Yep -- I noticed that to after the post `:)` More like `"If I go go to Mars I would need to turn left left to go to Venus Venus."` making that turn into `"If I go to Mars I would need to turn left to go to Venus."` (preserving the punctuation takes a bit of thought....)

Answer (score 0):

`std::set` and `std::unordered_set` can't store duplicate elements. Instead of explicitly calling `find` method on the `set`, you can use the values returned by `insert` method to determine whether the insertion was successful or not.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

void removeDupWord(std::string str)
{
    // Used to split string around spaces.
    std::istringstream ss(str);

    // To store individual visited words
    std::unordered_set<std::string> hsh;

    std::string word;
    // Traverse through all words
    while(ss >> word)
    {
        // Remove punctuation char from end
        if(std::ispunct(word.back()))
            word.pop_back();

        const auto& [itr, result] = hsh.insert(word);
        if( result )
            std::cout << word << ' ';   
    }

    // output
    // Welcome to the world of digital computers
}

int main()
{
    std::string input {"Welcome to to the world of of digital computers computers."};
    removeDupWord(input);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how to manage the dots and even the computers is dublicated.

Comment: You need an explicit condition to manage that situation because `computers` and `computers.` are  considered two distinct words.

Comment: @user15382501, As mentioned in the comments, you can check for punctuation characters at the end and remove it before storing it into the set. I've updated my answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

Following from the discussion in the comments, I tinkered a bit with a way to accomplish your goal of removing duplicate words (only if adjacent duplicates) and preserving the assumed punctuation at the end of the sentence. With tasks such as these, it's often easier to simply use a loop and a couple of variables to preserve the last word written and punctuation than trying to use some type of container to store and compare words.

The following does just that. It loops over each word, checking if the last character is punctuation with `std::ispunct()`, preserving the punctuation for appending later. To output the words a simple `first` state variable is used to determine the first output, allowing the space to be inserted *before* the next word rather than afterwards. That allows any punctuation removed for word comparison to be appended to the output as needed.

Below the program takes the sentence to process as the first argument to the program (could have just as easily read it from `stdin` -- up to you) and then outputs the corrected sentence below, e.g.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>

void removeDupWord(std::string str)
{
    bool first = true;            /* flag indicating 1st word output */
    std::istringstream ss(str);   /* initialize stringsream with str */
    std::string word, last {};
   
    while(ss >> word)     /* iterate over each word */
    {
        char c = 0;       /* if last char is punctuation, save in c */
        
        /* remove any punctuation from word */
        if (std::ispunct((unsigned char)word.back())) {
            c = word.back();
            word.pop_back();
        }
        
        if (word != last) {             /* if not duplicate of last word */
            if (!first) {               /* if not 1st word */
            std::cout << " " << word;   /* prepend space */
            }
            else {  /* otherwise */
                std::cout << word;      /* output word alone */
                first = false;          /* set first flag false */
            }
        }
        else if (c) {  /* otherwise word is adjacent duplicate */
            std::cout << c;  /* output trailing punctuation */
        }
        last = word;      /* update last to current word */
    }
    
    std::cout.put('\n');  /* tidy up with newline */
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2) {  /* ensure argument provided */
        return 1;
    }
    std::string input { argv[1] };  /* initialize string with argument */
    removeDupWord (input);          /* remove adjacent duplicate words */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your example sentence:

```
$ ./bin/unordered_set_rm_dup_words "Welcome to to the world of of digital computers computers."
Welcome to the world of digital computers.
```

And the longer example from the discussion with @PeteBecker in the comments:

```
$ ./bin/unordered_set_rm_dup_words "If I go go to Mars I would need to turn left left to go to Venus Venus."
If I go to Mars I would need to turn left to go to Venus.
```

It's up to you whether you simply compare, or choose to use a `std::unordered_set`, etc.. to store the words and compare. This, of course, turns on whether you want to remove ALL duplicate words, or just adjacent-duplicate words. Hard to tell what you need from your given example -- but my second example above, you can see the downside to removing ALL rather than just adjacent duplicates.

Any additional punctuation handling is left as an exercise for you. Let me know if you have questions.